# Problems with running remote daemon (and not only) processes via PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, remote-access, invoke-command

From my script I want to run some command in remote Windows box. So I googled a little and seems the most popular and somehow standard way to do that is to use PowerShell's `Invoke-Command` cmdlet which seems to use the same protocol as `winrm` and `winrs`. So, bellow are commands I've tried to call from my script (actually I've tried lots of other their modifications as well, but IMO these are enough to illustrate the problem):

1. `PowerShell -Command "$encpass=ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText mypass -Force;$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList myuser,$encpass; Invoke-Command -ComputerName REMOTE_COMPUTER_NAME -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {<fullcommand>};"`
2. `PowerShell -Command "$encpass=ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText mypass -Force;$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList myuser,$encpass; Invoke-Command -ComputerName REMOTE_COMPUTER_NAME -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {Start-Process -FilePath <fullexepath> -ArgumentList <arguments> -Wait -NoNewWindow};"`
3. `PowerShell -Command "$encpass=ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText mypass -Force;$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList myuser,$encpass;$session=new-PSSession -ComputerName "REMOTE_COMPUTER_NAME" -Credential $cred; Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {<fullcommand>};"`

***NOTE: The script is written in `perl`, but IMO here the language of the script doesn't matter, so you can suppose that I call the command from `batch` script, just note, that as commands should run from a script they should not require any interactive actions.***

So, I have several problems with these commands, and need help to figure them out. Here they are:

1. Can't run processes of type `configure and run daemon`. Namely if I want to run `configure_server.pl` on remote box (`<fullcommand> = "configure_server.pl <arguments>"`), which should do some stuff, then run `server.exe`, it doesn't work, because as soon as `configure_server.pl` is done, full remote job is being killed including the `server.exe` which supposed to run as a daemon. (applies to points 1,2,3)
2. Get wrapped (length of each line is less or equal than 80 chars) standard output and standard error. (applies to point 1,3)
3. Don't get standard output and standard error. (applies to point 2)

Answer (score 0):

Whew this is a tough one, your kind of all over the place so if I miss what your trying to do completely let me know.

1 . Stop trying to go the remote route. I know it seems like a great idea, but it's not. The only way you can get the process to persist is if you keep the powershell window up on the host computer. As you've probably noticed, you can create processes fine, but they're children of your powershell.exe, and are hosted by the wsmprovhost.exe process on the client computer. Once the parent is gone, all the children are killed

To fix this I suggest using a command line function : Schtasks.exe
`schtasks.exe /create /sc ONCE /tn $taskName /tr $command /s $serverName /u $userName /p $pass /ru $userName /rp $pass /st $startTime`

This command is going to create a scheduled task to run once and then remove itself after. It even takes computer name, so no remote-access required. You can also do a schtasks.exe /query and check the "Status" for running before you do a schtasks.exe /delete too.

2 .  Use the ` (backtick) to specify carry execution to the next line in powershell
3 . I get standard output and error with this function, sometimes not output when executed in a big script, but can always use $? to capture error.

Note: You cannot pass in PSCredentials to this command. I suggest making a GUI that just prompts for userName and and password, without converting to secure string. I try to stay away from remoting in my scripts, since it always just makes everything so slow. Sometimes you do not have a choice, but in this case I believe you do.